# write function which will display train details having maximum passanger for given date?

Tags: oracle, plsql

following are the table in database.
many to many relations between train and passenger

table 1 name=train

```
   TNO   TNAMe
```

---

```
     1   x
     2   y
     3   z
```

table 2 name=passenger

### PNO    PNAME

```
   111   a 
   222   b                 
   333   c 


   table 3 name=tp

    TNO      PNO     TPDATE
```

---

```
     1        111     23-NOV-15         
     2        222     24-JUN-14              
     3        222     19-JUN-13        
     1        333     23-NOV-15
```

using follwing code i only find out which train number has highest frequency
select tno,count(tno) as numberofoccurance from tp group by tno

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `group by` and `row_number` analytical function as following:

```
Select name, tp_date 
From
(Select t.tname tp.tp_date,
        row_number() over (partition by tp.tp_date order by count(1) desc nulls last) as cnt
From train t
Join tp tp
On (t.id = tp.tno)
Group by tp.tno, tp.tp_date)
Where cnt = 1;
```

Cheers!!